# Unable to store value NULL in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to store values in database.
How can I assign value NULL in the database, if it a an int.

Query:

```sql
@id varchar(10)
UPDATE [Table] SET 
      [id] = @id     -- id is an int in sql
```

C# code:

I pass the value:

```cs
    //dATABASE CONNECTION
 db.StoredProcedure = "UpdateProjectValues";
 db.Paramater("ID",TB_ID.TEXT); //tb_id.text=""
```

If it has value then that int will be stored but if I do not have the value, then 0 is getting stored, but i want NULL to be stored.

Comment: You may think you are passing `NULL`, but I'm guessing that you are passing an empty string.  I think that will be converted to `0` in this statement.

Comment: Please show your actual C# code. Also what is the type of `Table.id`? is it varchar(10) or is it `int` also is that column nullable?

Comment: YES, i THINK, EMPTY STRING IS GETTING PASSED. WHAT SHOULD I DO, TO STORE VALUE AS 'NULL'

Comment: If `tb_id_text="" then db.Paramter("ID", NULL)`

Comment: @user1989: **1.** -1 for a sloppily presented question. It usually pays off to properly layout & format & think through your question. Why did you leave irrelevant code comments in? And why did you omit relevant parts of your code? **2.** And while the Caps Lock key has its uses, writing a whole comment in SHOUTING MODE is not one of them.

Comment: @stakx the second comment was not in SHOUTING MODE, sometimes by mistake caps key is pressed and you see it only after you have commented. I didnt knew, you guys would see as shouting, sorry SHOUTING MODE

Answer (score 2):

One solution strictly inside the database is:

```
UPDATE [Table]
     SET [id] = (case when @id <> '' then cast(@id as int) end);
```

This makes the conversion explicit.  However, it is probably better to set up the C# code to pass in an integer value that can take on a `NULL` value.

Comment: This worked, but I dont understand, how this worked ?

Comment: @user1989 when @id is not a empty string (`@id <> ''`) then cast that value to a int (`cast(@id as int)`), when @id is a empty string nothing is done so NULL is returned from inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd provide a few alternatives:

1).  Handle the value in your stored procedure.  Gordon's CASE statement works but since you are using SQL Server you also have the NULLIF() function which you can use like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET [id] = NULLIF(@ID, '');
```

2.) Handle this in the C# code using a ternary operator like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UpdateProjectValues";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_ID.TEXT) ? DBNull.Value : (object)TB_ID.TEXT);
```

There are other ways also, but these are simple examples.